# How to validate an upgrade before installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, p2

We have an eclipse feature that is licensed and the license is handled by our own code. The user can go in on our update-site and upgrade his feature. The problem we face is when the user's license needs to be updated before he can use the new upgrade.

What I want to do is to validate the feature version against the users license and warn the user that his license needs to be updated before he install.

I thought I would do this using a custom eclipse p2 touchPoint action validateLicense.

Example:

My code is called, where I validate the version against the user's license. If it fails I warn the user and he can then cancel the installation.

So my first question is:

- Do I get this right, or is it some other way to do this?

My second question is pretty basic:

- Where do I tell eclipse to run my code?
  I have looked [here at eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html) where they explain what it is. But I don't understand where to put the information to run my code? Is it in the feature.xml.

Lastly:

- Is there an example how to create and use p2 touchPonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a custom action as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154367/a-working-example-of-custom-p2-provisioning-action) and I have a system that seems to work. I left out "touchpoint" extension as it's unnecessary in my case, but the rest is the same.

My action is executed during install phase of my feature (instructions.install) but maybe configure phase could work too. Collect phase did not work.

The action is executed during installation process, after the download was already performed. Ideally it would be before the download but it's not a big issue for me. Returning an error status from the action cancels the install. It leaves some downloaded files around but they do not get activated and are probably removed later by p2's garbage collector.

I also managed to do some more interesting things. My actions plugin has a dependency (optional and non-greedy) on my main plugin. So the install works like this:

- Actions plugin is downloaded
- Custom action is executed
- The action detects whether my main plugin is already installed and if yes, it calls into it to retrieve licensing info. The main plugin has to expose an API for the action. The action also checks main plugin's version to detect whether the API is there or not.
- The action now can decide whether to proceed or cancel the install. It can even interact with the user using Display#syncExec (this is what the code in checkTrust phase does so I think it's safe). If needed, the action could also detect whether the install is headless.

Some gotchas:

- Action itself must be versioned. It's the version you declare in plugin.xml and p2.inf files and it's different from plugin's version. I just replace 1.0.0 with the same version my plugin has. This way the latest version of the action plugin is always downloaded before being executed. This is great because now any problem changes to licensing rules can be implemented in actions plugin.
- Actions API changed between Eclipse 3.5 and 3.6. I will probably drop support for 3.5 as it's pretty old anyway.
- Actions plugin should probably be signed. It's the case in my case. The system seems almost too powerful to me as just pointing Eclipse to an update site gets it to execute downloaded code.

I still need to test how this works with different versions of Eclipse and other IDEs. I saw a strange (non-blocking) error with 3.6. However the results are promising and it looks like the system might actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Touchpoints are executed at installation time, which means that the resolution (validation) has already happened. I'm not sure they would help.  What about creating an Installable Unit (IU) (or Eclipse Feature) that represents the license the user has installed. Then you would put a dependency from your product to that license.

For example, create an IU called com.mycompany.license (1.0.0). You would create another one called com.mycompany.license (2.0.0).  When you installed a license, the appropriate IU would be added to the profile.

Now, when you go to install you product, the new version of the product would require license version 2.0.0. If this license was not installed, the resolution would fail.

Does this make sense? Do you think this would help?

Comment: It is an interesting idea, but will this make it possible for me to run code? It doesn't matter if it happening before or after installation just that it happens around install. Is it some good documentation about this somewhere that you know about?

Comment: Why do you want to run code? If you need to run arbitrary code, then yes, you will need a touchpoint. But a touchpoint can't cause the installation to fail (well, I guess you could throw an exception and try to roll everything back, but that's not really their job). If you want to validate that the license is actually correct, I would do this at runtime (not install time), and just use the IU trick to make sure that the user doesn't get in an invalid state.  As for docs, there is a bit here http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Customizing_Metadata.

Comment: The validation needs to run some code to be able to validate. I.e check against a server or in some cases only check the "keystore". The idea to throw an exception or just return false during a check, like if you are missing a dependency was what I wanted to do. But I just can't get it to work. I'll have a closer look at the IU but at first glance it doesn't seem to really help me. Thanks thou!

Comment: In my test an action can cause the installation to fail by simply returning an error status from the execute method.